# Em Python, como remover caracteres específicos de todos os registros de apenas uma determinada coluna?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, ipython-notebook

estou no Jupyter Notebook trabalhando com Python.

O dataframe possui algumas colunas, porém, em uma coluna específica, desejo excluir todos os registros que terminam com ".txt", ou seja, os 4 últimos caracteres.

Imagem do dataframe:
[image: Imagem do dataframe]

Desejo ter como resultado todas estas linhas sem os caracteres ".txt".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma outra forma, além de usar map (como apontado em outra resposta), é utilizar a conversão e os métodos de string fornecidos pelo pandas, assim:

```py
raw_data['nome_arquivo'].str.rstrip('.txt')
```

O trecho acima é apenas uma das soluções, mas qualquer outro método de string pode ser utilizado após o `.str`, como por exemplo o `replace` (`raw_data['nome_arquivo'].str.replace('.txt', '')`).

Comment: Grato, este comando funcionou na saída. Porém, ao executar o dataframe raw_data novamente, apresenta todas as outras colunas e esta, mas sem o ajuste anterior sem os ".txt".

Comment: @Perciliano é que tem que fazer `raw_data['nome_arquivo'] = raw_data['nome_arquivo'].str.rstrip('.txt')`

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o apply e fazer um slicing da string

```
raw_data['nome_arquivo'] = raw_data['nome_arquivo'].apply(lambda x: x[:-4])
```

Pode também utilizar o replace

```
raw_data['nome_arquivo'] = raw_data['nome_arquivo'].str.replace('.txt','')
```

Entrada

```
                                        ARQUIVOS
0   AAAAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB.txt
1   AAAAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB.txt
2   AAAAAAAAAAFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB.txt
3   AAAAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBBBB.txt
4   AAAAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB.txt
5   AAAAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB.txt
6   AAAAAAAAAAAFFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB.txt
7   AAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB.txt
```

Saída

```
                                    ARQUIVOS
0   AAAAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB
1   AAAAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB
2   AAAAAAAAAAFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB
3   AAAAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBBBB
4   AAAAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB
5   AAAAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB
6   AAAAAAAAAAAFFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB
7   AAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Comment: Grato, mas estes comandos não funcionaram.

Comment: @Perciliano, atualizei a resposta, veja se agora funciona. Abraço!